# Install Mongo DB in Windows XP

Tags: mongodb, windows-xp, mean-stack, mean, database

How I am Suppose to Install **Mongo DB** on Windows XP.
I tried with different article available on the web but that did not worked.

Current Stable Release (3.2.8) version is not available for windows XP.

Comment: What didn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: downloaded "mongodb-win32-i386-3.2.8-signed.msi" windows installer package and executed the downloaded file.
when tried to run "mongod.exe" file from path"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin"
Its says mongod.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Maybe you can try installing this one: http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.2.8-signed.msi

Comment: On Installation "This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor." this error pop up appeared.

Comment: Have you created these directories data\db in c ??

Answer (score 1):

You can download a zip archive, extract it, and start using MongoDB. For example, downloads for win32/i386 may be found  [here](https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386). Then just launch mongod.exe with appropriate arguments or install it as a service. You may also find [this article](https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/10/install-setup-and-start-mongodb-on-windows/) helpful.